# A bit confused about java datatypes and literals

Tags: java

So I understand what a dataype and literal is but I am confused about one thing.
Why do I have to put an L when the datatype is long? How come I don't have to do that for short or byte?

```
// Why does a not work but b does? Both are longs? 

long a = 9223372036854775807;
long b = 9223372036854775807L;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two integer literals types defined in Java: `int` and `long`.  The latter is distinguished from the former by a suffix `L` or `l`.  (A character literal is also of integral type (can be assigned to an `int`, for example) but the Java Language Specification (JLS) treats it separately from integer literals.)

Remember that (apart from inferring generic type parameters), the type of the left hand side of an assignment has no effect on the evaluation of the right-hand side.  Therefore, if you assign something to a variable of type `long`, the expression will be evaluated *first* and only then will the result be converted to `long` (if possible and necessary).

The statement

```
long a = 10;
```

is perfectly valid.  The right hand side expression consisting only of the integer literal `10` will be evaluated and then promoted to `long` which is then assigned to the variable `a`.  This works well unless you want to assign a value that is too large to be represented in an `int` in which case you'll have to make the literal of type `long` as well.

This “problem” is not limited to literals.  Consider the following statement that frequently bites new users:

```
long a = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1;
```

The expression on the right hand side is evaluated using `int` arithmetic and therefore overflows.  Only then the result (−2147483648) is promoted to `long` and assigned to `a` but it is too late by now.  Had the `1` been written as `1L`, the overflow would not have happened.

> How come I don't have to do that for `short` or `byte`?

First, note that a literal of type `int` can hold any value you could possibly assign to a `short` or `byte` so the problem described above cannot occur.  Moreover, it is not as much that you “don't have to” use a `short` or `byte` literal but that you *cannot* because such literals are not defined.  This has always bothered me because it means that we often have to cast to `byte` if we want to call a function with a literal argument.

If you like reading standardese, you can look up the chapter about [*Integer Literals* (§ 3.10.1) in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

"An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish from the digit 1."

Your 2nd question is answered there as well:

"Values of the integral types byte, short, int, and long can be created from int literals"

Comment: But whats the point of using the datatype long then if its treated as an int?

Comment: @ReeceLeu: The variable on the left side is a long. But that does not automatically make the literal on the right side a long as well. If it did, where to stop? Should `long x = "1234";` also work?

Comment: All programming languages actually face the same problem. Each defines its own rule regarding the type of integer literal. Java in this case choose to pick int by default, or long if it has L/l suffix. Other languages may have integer promotion rule (e.g.: int always fits in long, so int literal can be assigned to long variable by promoting its type to long), or simply treat each literal as the widest integer type the compiler supports. It's a design decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't set L, the compiler will try to parse the literal as an int like as below sample scenario.

long accepts a value between the ranges of: -9,223,372,036,854 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807. Now I have create a Long variable called testLong, although when I insert 9223372036854775807 as the value, I get an error stating:

"The literal of int 9223372036854775807 is out of range."

Solution is add a capital L to the end: